# google recaptcha without any form or submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, installation, recaptcha

I want to setup security challenge google re-captcha front of my site without
any form. for example, if a visitor try to visit on my site (http://domain.com)
they need to pass security challenge(google captcha) without filling any form.
and when he/she passed security challenge the security page will move him
automatically to the main page of my site (http://domain.com/wellcome).
can someone help me how I don this?

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation it seems there are several ways of checking.
If I read correctly by adding a data attribute (data-callback) with your javascript function name in, it will be called once they have been verified.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

So you could use a function that then redirects them like:

```
function redirect(){
   window.location = "http://domain.com/welcome";
}
```

Comment: can you provide full page coding?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't for sharing entire blocks of code, merely snippets, tips and improvements.

Sorry.

If you attempt it yourself, we will be able to assist you.

Comment: ok, check this url and tell me which code me need to edit to i get my solution. https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial

Comment: That doesn't do what you need. For you the keyword is Ajax.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006081/recaptcha-2-0-with-ajax

Comment: You don't seem to be grasping the whole idea behind us giving tips and not code. Show us what you tried and will we explain what you are missing and/or what needs to be changed.